# Can I do something like [a,b,c] = [1,2,3] in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to be able to do this kind of assignment in node js:

```
[a,b,c] = [1,2,3]
```

or just like in python

```
a,b,c = 1,2,3
```

so that I would have a=1, b=2 and b=3.

Actually the purpose of this is to do something like

```
[a,b,c] = somefunc()
```

or for array declaration

```
[a,b,c] = [[],[],[]]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not yet - Node.js uses V8 engine, which implements ECMA Script 5.

But this functionality will be avialable in the next, ECMA Script 6, release. It's described i.e. [in this blog post](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/02/es6-and-destructuring-assignment.html) or on [this wiki](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3adestructuring). V8 (thus Node.js as well) will implement it, as [per this issue](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=811).

Once it's implemented, it'll look like this:

```
[a, b] = [b, a]
```

or this:

```
function f() { return [1, 2, 3] }
var [a, , b] = f();
```

(examples from the wiki).

---

If you really need this, you can always use tools like [Google Traceur compiler](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler) which allows you to write ES6 code and "compile" it into JavaScript compatible with all modern browsers (and Node.js).

Comment: Anyway, I just love node js...

Answer (score 5):

"Node" isn't a language. You're really asking if you can do this in JavaScript, and no, you can't. There isn't any form of [destructured assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7#Destructuring_assignment_%28Merge_into_own_page.2Fsection%29) in JavaScript (prior to 1.7), and no way of making anything like that work. You cannot assign to an array.

*Unless* you're using JavaScript 1.7. Then it will work exactly as you've written it.